# closure of intersection under projection

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $Z=\{(x,y)\in R^d\times R^l: a\leq Ax\leq b,  y=Bx\}$ where $A,B$ are matrices and $a, b$ are vectors in $R^m$, with $a_i\leq b_i$, for all $i=1,...,m$.

Then $Z=Z_1\cap Z_2$ where

$Z_1=\{(x,y):  Ax\leq b,  y=Bx\}$,

$Z_2=\{(x,y):  Ax\geq a,  y=Bx\}$.

For any $P\subset R^d\times R^l$, define the projection of $P$ onto $y$-space by

$proj_y(P)=\{y\in R^l: \exists x\in R^d \,\,\,such\,\, that\,\,\, (x,y)\in P\}.$

I want to show that the projection of the intersection of the projections  of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ onto $y$-space equals to the projection of $Z$ onto $y$-space, i.e.

$$Proj_y (Z_1)\cap Proj_y (Z_2)=Proj_y (Z).$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you precise what you name projection onto $y$-space?

Comment: Hi, I make a revision on the problem.

Comment: And in which set are $a,b$?

Comment: Here $a,b$ are vectors in $R^m$, with $a_i\leq b_i $ for all $i=1,...,m$.